# Django - formset for updating a field, formset is not valid

Tags: django-views, django-forms

I have a model that contains a name and email fields.  I would like to display a template that has a formset (modelformset) to update the email field for a given queryset on that model.

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_first = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    student_last = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    student_number = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['student_first']
```

views.py

```
def editstudentemail(request, classroom_pk):
    classblock = get_object_or_404(Classroom, pk=classroom_pk)
    students = Student.objects.filter(classroom=classblock).order_by('student_first')
    EditEmailFormSet = modelformset_factory(Student, fields=('email',), extra=0)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = EditEmailFormSet(request.POST, queryset=students)
        if formset.is_valid():
            print("valid")
            instances = formset.save()
        else:
            print("not valid")
        return redirect('gradebook:classroomdetail', classroom_id=classroom_pk)

    formset = EditEmailFormSet(queryset=students)
    context = {'classblock': classblock}
    context['students'] = students
    context['formset'] = formset

    return render(request, 'gradebook/editstudentemail.html', context)
```

template:

```
{% if students %}
  <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for ss in students %}
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <b>{{ ss.student_first }}</b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                {% for form in formset %}
                    {% if forloop.parentloop.counter == forloop.counter %}
                        {{ form|crispy }}<br/>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        <hr/>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-2" />
  </form>
{% endif %}
```

The nested for loop in the template is so I can print the student name beside the form input box for editing the email. (Perhaps there is a better way to do this, maybe it's possible to include the field `student_first` in the formset but make it not editable.)

I think I might not be saving the forms/formset correctly, but my first problem is that when I view this template, `not valid` is printed to the console. There aren't any errors, `formset.is_valid()` is returning `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, I need to explicitly add the `managementform` to the template:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for ss in students %}
    ...
```

I had seen the [managementform mentioned in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform) but it wasn't clear to me if/when it would be added to a template.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
instances = formset.save(commit=False)
for instance in instances:
     instance.save()
```

Essentially save the instances individually